# Get current user id in Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-login

I'm quite new to Python (and, to be honest, programming in general). I'm currently working on a kind of to-do list, where I need it to put to-do items into appropriate course (it's all related to educational stuff). So, the problem is quite straight-forward. I have this as a Flask-driven route:

```
@app.route('/add_course', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@login_required
def course():
    form = forms.CourseForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        models.Course.create(teacher=g.user._get_current_object(),
                             name=form.name.data.strip(),
                             difficulty=form.level.data.strip(),
                             description=form.description.data.strip())
        flash("Course successfully created!", "success")
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('add_course.html', form=form)
```

Then I have this in `forms.py`. You can see the clever mark that I have put to indicate where my problem is. It says `THE_PROBLEM`

```
def courses():
    try:
        courses = models.Course.select(models.Course.id,
                                   models.Course.name,
                                   models.Course.difficulty).where(THE_PROBLEM)
        course_list = []
        for course in courses:
            course_list.append((str(course.id), course.name + ' - ' + course.difficulty.title()))
        return course_list
    except models.DoesNotExist:
        return [('', 'No courses')]


class ToDoForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField("What's up?", validators=[
    DataRequired()
    ])
    due_date = DateTimeField('When?', format='%Y-%m-%d %H-%M')
    course = SelectField('Course', choices=courses())
    priority = SelectField('Priority',
                           choices=[('high', 'High priority'),
                                    ('medium', 'Normal priority'),
                                    ('low', 'Low priority')],
                           validators=[
                               DataRequired()
                           ])
    description = TextAreaField('Description')
```

So, yeah, what I am looking for is the way to pass the id of the owner (teacher in this very case) who is currently logged in. I use this function `courses()` to build a list of tuples for the choices attribute of the field `course` in `ToDoForm`. I need to pass the id of currently logged-in teacher into this function, so that it can evaluate if this passed teacher has any courses that match his id. I tried to use `current_user._get_current_object()` and whatever else, but it just caused me tons of errors.

Any help, advice or suggestion will be appreciated. I really hope that what I say here (and what I want to achieve) is understandable

Comment: You didn't address what is happening when a user logs in, but I suspect what you need here is session management. When a user logs in a profile should be compared against in the database. Upon success, a user session would be initiated and from there you could store whatever initial values might of of interest to you, in this case the user id. Does this sound about right?

Comment: Well, I bet this wasn't self-explanatory. Sorry for that. Well, I have the LoginManager instantiated in my app.py (given up above as the first code block) and my forms in forms.py (the second block of code). Everything works correctly and there's no problem about that. I just wanted a hand in another question - how do I provide the id of the current user? In other words, I want to build a query like "SELECT name, difficulty FROM course WHERE teacher_id = ** Currently logged in user **. This is the problem for me as this evaluation process is happening in forms.py, not in app.py.

Comment: @SergeyOrlov - `from flask_login import current_user`

Comment: @pjcunningham It's imported. How do I retrieve the id from this object?

Comment: @SergeyOrlov - in your Flask-Login setup you should have created a User class. `current_user` is the instance of this class of the current logged in user. So the id will be `current_user.id`

Comment: @SergeyOrlov - `current_user.get_id()` - I was thinking of Flask-Security.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your replies and spending your time trying to understand me :D So, the approach I took was wrong from the beginning as I tried to call classes from external scripts and wanted to somehow put variables from outer scope into those classes. Badly-Oriented Programming.

Answer (score -7):

In case anybody runs into the same frustrating problem, the solution is quite straightforward. Wrap up external classes into functions and pass required variables as arguments, then use them to your heart's content.
Just don't forget to return an instance of the class.